# UIDocumentInteractionController doesn't work on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I need to send file from one application to another. I use [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to copy file. 
Here is my code implementing `UIDocumentInterationController` in my `ViewController` in SendingApp.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"zip"];
NSURL *urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:urlPath];
[docController retain];
docController.delegate = self;
[docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.frame
                                  inView:self.view
                                animated:YES];
```

docController is property. `ViewController` implements `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`.

The ReceiverApp is set to handle the files of this extension. 
My ReceiverAppInfo.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>zip</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>ZIP</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.zip-archive</string>
            <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

In ReceiverAppDelegate I use

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

to handle opening of receiving file.

**So problem** is that this code works just perfect on iOS 5.1 **BUT** it doesn't work on iOS 6. UIDocumentInteractionController OpenIn menu appears and shows my ReceiverApp but it doesn't do anything if you select the app. I looked in Console and found out that iPhone Simulator 6.1 tries to copy file to one directory while Simulator 5.1 copies to another.

iPhoneSimulator 6.1

```
com.apple.mdt[2342]: 
Copy ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/367D395F-DC8B-4F4C-83C7-B22992E34C64/sendingZIP.app/1.zip -> 
/var/mobile/Library/Application Support/Containers/-23.ReceiveApp/Documents/Inbox
```

iPhoneSimulator 5.1

```
com.apple.mdt[2439]: 
Copy ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/0DE1852A-F803-4583-87BC-8F1EBBE362A4/sendingZIP.app/1.zip -> 
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/927E310A-2766-4709-81CB-0E759F24236D/Documents/Inbox
```

Has anybody such problem? Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Also having this issue on iOS 6 but not iOS 7 now

Answer (score -1):

Notice that the only discernible API difference is

> **Managing Actions**
>   – documentInteractionController:canPerformAction: Deprecated in iOS 6.0
>   – documentInteractionController:performAction: Deprecated in iOS 6.0

Are you still implementing these methods? Maybe they are responsible for the unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't use them. I tried to delete all about UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate but it didn't help.